# How to select mulitple items with listview using checkbox in react native?

Tags: checkbox, react-native, react-native-listview

I'm working on listview with checkbox. I'm trying to select multiple items but I discovered something in the result that every time I click the checkbox the result is replacing the first item that I checked

here's my case:

```
    this.state = {
     ...
     checkedBoxCheck: false,
     selectedItems:[],
   };

    renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            ...
           <CheckBox style={styles.checkboxed}
              checked={rowData.id === this.state.checkedBoxCheck}
              onPress={() => this.onItemSelect(rowData)}
            />
        );

onItemSelect(row){
    this.setState({
        selectedItems: [{row}],
        checkedBoxCheck: true,
    });
    let myitem = this.state.selectedItems.concat({row});
    console.log(myitem);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to write in the state the previous values selectedItems:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    selectedItems: [...prevState.selectedItems, row],
    checkedBoxCheck: true,
}));
```

And deleting value (with lodash):

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    selectedItems: _.without(prevState.selectedItems, row),
    checkedBoxCheck: !!_.without(prevState.selectedItems, row).length,
}));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I got selectedItems undefined and setState is not a function.

Comment: checked={rowData.id === this.state.checkedBoxCheck} what is it? You have array in state, you can not make a comparison this way.

Comment: [{row}] it is [ { row: row } ] but I do not understand why you are doing this

Comment: Sorry, I thought this line --- checked={rowData.id === this.state.checkedBoxCheck} causes the problem why the checked box is not showing I forgot to delete that,

Comment: onItemSelect(row){
        this.setState({
            selectedItems: [{row}],
            checkedBoxCheck: true,
        });
      
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    selectedItems: [...prevState.selectedItems, row],
    checkedBoxCheck: true,
}));

        console.log(this.state.selectedItems.concat([{row}]))
    }

Comment: change this.setState in function onItemSelect. 
If you want me to help you fix the code for your component, please show the entire component. From this code that you sent me, I do not understand anything. Use the gist

Comment: @kkumber https://gist.github.com/TemaKozyrev/40337a569ae397ab19b76453f1dfaf5c/revisions

Comment: Thank you so much for this . I really appreciate your help. But one last thing in the result I cannot get the item that I selected it logged as empty array. .

Comment: I cannot get the Items that I selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the select field of Form Builder.
https://github.com/bietkul/react-native-form-builder